# Make Convert.ToDouble work with different CultureInfos

Tags: c#, double, cultureinfo

Whats the best way to make the conversion work when you have:

```
string a = "10.0123";
string b = "10,0123";
```

And the cultureinfo is either swedish or english, it needs to work with both.

I tried:

```
double aSwe = Convert.ToDouble(a, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"));
double bSwe = Convert.ToDouble(b, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"));

double aInv = Convert.ToDouble(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double bInv = Convert.ToDouble(b, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Since '.' is not a valid separator in Swe and ',' is not valid in Eng I dont know how to make it work with both using the same code.
Only solution I come up with is to replace the comma or dot before converting but it feels like there should be better solution?

Answer (score 3):

You *shouldn't* try to make it work with both without any extra context.

It's like trying to parse "06/05/2010" as a date without any cultural information: it could mean the May 6th or June 5th.

Likewise "1,234" is either a value a bit more than a thousand, or a bit more than one: you **need** to know the cultural information in order to interpret it unambiguously.

So instead of trying to solve the problem of interpreting something without enough information, I suggest you focus on the problem of getting all the information you need (or changing the way you get your text data to always be in one particular format).

Comment: Good to know. But even if I know the culture is English it wouldnt be possible to convert a value with the same line of code if the values seperator is something different from '.'? So then the only thing left to do is to replace the ',' with a '.'?

Comment: @mdc: If you know the culture is English, then how could the decimal separator be something different to `.`? That *is* the separator in English (or rather in all the *specific* English cultures I'm aware of). If you've got a string of "1,5" meaning "one and a half" then that *isn't* in an English culture.

Comment: I meant the culture set on the users device. The string I receive is out of my control and can be either 1.5 or 1,5.

Comment: @mdc: then you *don't* know that the culture is English. I would argue that if the user is giving you invalid data for the culture they've specified on their device, you're within your rights to ask them to change either their culture or the data. Again, what would you do with an ambiguous date?

Comment: I said if I know that if their cultural setting is set to English on their device. And as I said I cant do anything about the data because its from another part of the system that uses both formats. I dont have different kinds of dates to work with so that is not a problem right now.

Comment: @mdc: Well, you said "even if I know the culture is English" - the culture *on the device* and the culture that the data is in sound like they could be different. If you're really in that broken a situation, I suspect you'll have to do a search/replace and *hope* that you don't get something like "1,234" which is ambiguous. Do any of your values use thousands separators?